# SMS não recebida

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sms

Estou tentando aprender a mexer com o [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) aplicando ele a um projeto, de teste mesmo, em ASP.NET MVC 5.

Em meio a minha escavação no Google, eu achei [esse tutorial aqui](http://delegadoanonimo.github.io/2014/11/25/sms-as-a-service-com-twilio/) que explica como utilizá-lo.

Fiz tudo de acordo com o que ta nesse tutorial, mas na hora de testar, eu até recebo a mensagem que o SMS foi enviado, mas não recebo mensagem nenhuma em meu numero....

Não sei se eu estou fazendo alguma coisa errada no meu código, ou se estou errando na configuração no site mesmo. Sei que números brasileiros gerados pelo twilio não enviam mensagem ainda, então acabei criando uma outra conta e mudando o numero, pois conta free não pode trocar de numero.

Sei também que podemos usar credenciais de teste para enviar mensagens sem a necessidade de pagar por isso. Mas elas até funcionam, mas nada de receber mensagem...

Enfim, vou colocar aqui o controller (apesar de achar que o problema é na minha conta) pra que alguém possa me ajudar.

## Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.SendSmsResultMessage = TempData.ContainsKey("SendSmsResultMessage") ? TempData["SendSmsResultMessage"] : String.Empty;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult SendSms(string sid, string token, string fromPhoneNumber, string toPhoneNumber, string message)
     {
         var twilioClient = new TwilioRestClient(sid, token);
         var sendMessageResult = twilioClient.SendMessage(fromPhoneNumber, toPhoneNumber, message, "");

         if (sendMessageResult.RestException == null)
             TempData["SendSmsResultMessage"] = "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!";
         else
             TempData["SendSmsResultMessage"] = "Houve um erro durante a tentativa de enviar a mensagem: " + sendMessageResult.RestException.Message;

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
```

Alguém já usou o serviço deles que possa me ajudar ? Seja um outro tutorial de como criar numeros e fazer esse envio de teste ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/which-countries-does-twilio-have-phone-numbers-in-and-what-are-their-capabilities) essa funcionalidade não está disponível no Brasil.

Os países que possuem essa funcionalidade (SMS gratuito) são:

Australia, Austria, Belgium, Canada, Estonia, Finland, Germany, Hong Kong, Ireland, Lithuania, Mexico, Norway, Poland, Puerto Rico, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United Kingdom e
United States.

Já para ligações, o Brasil está incluído na lista dos países que possuem essa função.

Apenas um lembrete:

> The rest of the world…
>   Twilio is in the process of providing phone numbers in more countries as quickly as we can. Each country has different regulations regarding the purchase and sale of telephone numbers, so we are not able to provide a timeline on when numbers in a specific country will be available.

Ou seja: o "Twilio está em processo de fornecer números de telefone em mais países o mais rápido possível. Cada país tem diferentes regulamentações relativas a compra e venda de números de telefone, de modo que não somos capazes de fornecer um cronograma sobre quando os números em um país específico estará disponível."

Comment: Então eu teria que comprar um numero pra que ele possa enviar uma mensagem pra números brasileiros certo ?

Comment: não funciona no Brasil. Você terá que recorrer a outro serviço.

Comment: valeu pelo esclarecimento. Andei lendo a documentação nesse link que me enviou e adicionei mais algumas informações a sua resposta! Valeu.